# Why isn't shutdown giving me a chance to save files in running programs?

Tags: shutdown

When I shutdown the computer, Ubuntu just kills all the programs I have out and I was wondering if there was a way to change it so that it lets the programs ask if I want to save my document first or something along those lines?

Answer (score 2):

If you shutdown or logout from the cog menu (top right), Ubuntu does this anyway. How are you shutting down (or have you changed any settings)?

[image]